# Datetime Calculation in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm stuck in the problem of time calculation in php. I'll tell you with my example:

I hosted a greeting website on web-server and this server is in India. It means the server is running on Indian Time zone. Now lets think today date is '01/01/2013' and I want to send a greeting to UK on next day 02/01/2013 in the morning 0:00AM (12:00AM). If I submit my greeting card, my php script will send this card by India timezone, which means when 12AM in India the script will run and send the card and UK will receive this card 5 hour before the exact time. I know how to get the correct time of any country I used time offset to get the time.

`$time = strtotime('H:m:s'.(time() - (serverOffset - ukOffset)))`

So what is the way to set the time to 00:00AM or how much hours left in current time to 00:00AM. Is there any procedure?

**[NEW UPDATE]**

**OK I GOT THE SOLUTION**

```
$SERVER_OFFSET = 19800; //INDIA +5.50
$PARIS_TZ_HOUR = 1.0; //FRANCE-PARIS +1.00
$NEW_OFFSET = ($PARIS_TZ_HOUR * (60*60)); //new_offset 3600
$MINUTES = ($SERVER_OFFSET - $NEW_OFFSET)/60; 

// Lets date is: 2013-01-20 00:00:00
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($MINUTES.'minutes', strtotime('2013-01-19')));
```

**IN SIMPLE WORD:**
**(19800-3600)/60 = 270 (minutes)**

270 minutes, which means 4.5 hours
So when India time will 2013-01-20 00:00
Then it will 2013-01-19 19:30:00 in France
or
If India time is 2013-01-20 04:30 it will 2013-01-20 00:00 in France :)
I used Minutes instead of adding hours, because minutes will give you more accurate result rather then hour.

Thats it, Hope it will help you people

Comment: If you found one of the solutions below helpful, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: ok done it, sorry i didnt update this.. check this solution in question details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always set the timezone by using date_default_timezone_set() like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

But if you don't want to do that, you can get the timestamp for 00:00am (12am) by doing something like this:

```
$ukOffset = 60*60*5.5; // UK is 5 hours 30 mins behind India's time
$midnight = strtotime('7 January 2013');
$midnightUK = $midnight-$ukOffset;
```

Or if you want to see how much time is left between now and then you can do something like this:

```
$ukOffset = 60*60*5.5;
$midnight = strtotime('7 January 2013');
$midnightUK = $midnight-$ukOffset;
$difference = $midnightUK - (time()-$ukOffset);
```

Comment: actually i cannot use date_default_timezone_set, because as i said im creating e-greeting website, and i will use CRONJOB as a my greeting sender, my database will have mix country data, i want to calculate the dates then save this in my database. means, convert the another country time on the basis of server time, when server time is 5:00(IST) the UK time will 00:00(12AM)... sry for bad english :P you can understand what i want to say.... anyway i will try your code and reply you back.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know if setting the timezone would work for you or not, but I figured I would go ahead and suggest it anyway because if it would work, it would save you quite a bit of code. Please let me know if you need anymore help, I would be glad to assist you.

Comment: thank you, when i solved my problem, i will publish the method in here, which help the other people too. ;)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please up-vote or accept it by clicking the ^ arrow or the check mark below the arrows. Thanks!

Comment: If you do date arithmetics like 60*60*5.5 you will likely run into problems with DST. Use `strtotime` instead.

Comment: I posted the solution in my question details, check this out :)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP there is more than one way to achieve what you're looking for.

1) If you're specially looking for UK, you can use `gmdate` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

2) Using DateTime class's setTimezone method. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

3) Using date_default_timezone_set method. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

You will find good examples on php online manual and both 2) and 3) should be helpful to you for setting any possible timezone and trigger events on specified time.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the timezone you want to use at run time in your card script?

At the top of your script...

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this assuming that your server is 5 hours behind the desired timezone.

```
$date = date('h:i:s A', strtotime($today)+(60*60*5)); // $today is today date
```

Comment: The UK is actually 5 hours and 30 minutes behind India, not 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's DateTime classes makes this problem trivial. I set up this code to demonstrate:-

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');//As my dev machine is on GMT, you probably don't need this.
$date = new DateTime();
var_dump($date);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
var_dump($date);
```

Output:-

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2013-01-07 19:44:08' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Asia/Kolkata' (length=12)
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2013-01-07 14:14:08' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/London' (length=13)
```

Basically, this demonstrates that you can take your server time and compare it directly to UK time to send your message at the correct time.

See the [DateTime<sup>Docs</sup> manual](http://php.net/DateTime) for more information.